# Persist bestmodel from pipeline in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a question regards how to extract pipeline's bestmodel for scoring and further use. For example i have tried saving it to pmml file using JPMML pyspark2 library but i came to issue saving the file. Is there a other way of saving the pipeline model using pyspark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `bestModel` function on your trained model `transformer` like this ...

```py
print(spark.version)
2.4.3

# fit model on training data to cv/grid search
cvModel = cv_grid.fit(train_df)

# save best model from cv grid search
mPath =  "/path/to/model/folder"
cvModel.bestModel.write().overwrite().save(mPath)

# read pickled model via pipeline api
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import PipelineModel
persistedModel = PipelineModel.load(mPath)

# predict
predictionsDF = persistedModel.transform(test_df)
```

Source code for an extra read => https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/tuning.html